# How can I make a persistent drawer with routes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Right now I have a class for my drawer that all of my pages' scaffold's use. When I push a new route, the drawer resets the state. Is there any way I can combat this? I'm trying to make a drawer that changes the background of the selected item based on the route but when I click my custom list tile, it just only highlights the first item in the drawer which is not the desired result.

At the top of the state class:

```dart
    int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Here's some of the code:

```dart
      ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _drawerItems.length,
        // primary: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          DrawerItem currentItem = _drawerItems[index];
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(50))),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                currentItem.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontFamily: "Muli",
                  letterSpacing: .3,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Icon(currentItem.icon, color: Colors.black),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                });
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(routes[index]);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push a new route, it makes a new drawer and the current drawer gets disposed. so the `setState` does nothing.

you should try to declare `selectedIndex` as a static [or a global] variable and change your onTap to:

```dart
              onTap: () {
                selectedIndex = index;
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(routes[index]);
              },
```